# How to get output into GUI text widgets in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was given the code for two text widgets for a program I have to write.

```
player1_label = Label(window,text='Player 1:')
player1_label.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='W')
player1_score = Label(window)
player1_score.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='W')
player1_text = Text(window,width=30)
player1_text.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=3,padx=10,pady=10)

player2_label = Label(window,text='Player 2:')
player2_label.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky='W')
player2_score = Label(window)
player2.grid(row=0,column=4,sticky='W')
player2_text = Text(window,width=30)
player2_text.grid(row=1,column=3,columnspan=3)

action_button = Button(window,text='Play',command=play_action)
action_button.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2)
action_button['state'] = NORMAL
```

I've written a function for `do_action()` which results in printing something. When I hit the action button, the strings I'm printing end up in interpreter rather than the text widgets. How do I designate which strings go into which widget and which window of the widget?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
print('hello')
```

do

```
player2_text.insert(END, 'hello')
```

or similar.

Read up on [`tkinter`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) to get a handle on how to manipulate the various widgets.